# java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'inventory-service' [A(1), AAAA(28)] after 6 queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I'm using Java 17, Spring Boot v3.1.3 and Spring Cloud stack to perform interservice communication.

I'm receiving this error when I make a POST request to http://localhost:8081/api/order

order-service error:

```java
    java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'inventory-service' [A(1), AAAA(28)] after 6 queries 
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1097) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1044) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:432) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.onResponse(DnsResolveContext.java:662) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$500(DnsResolveContext.java:66) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:489) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.trySuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:317) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.finishSuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:309) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver$DnsResponseHandler.channelRead(DnsNameResolver.java:1392) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:97) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

pom.xml

```java
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

WebClientConfig class:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

OrderService class:

```java
    private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    public void placeOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderNumber(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        List<OrderLineItems> orderLineItems = orderRequest.getOrderLineItemsDto()
                .stream()
                .map(this::mapToDto)
                .toList();
        order.setOrderLineItems(orderLineItems);

        List<String> skuCodes = order.getOrderLineItems().stream()
                .map(OrderLineItems::getSkuCode)
                .toList();

        InventoryResponse[] inventoryResponses = webClientBuilder.build().get()
                .uri("http://inventory-service/api/inventory",
                        uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("skuCode", skuCodes).build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(InventoryResponse[].class)
                .block();
```

application.properties:

```java
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/order-service
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.application.name=order-service

server.port=8081

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

application.properties from inventory-service:

```java
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/inventory-service
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.application.name=inventory-service

server.port=0

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

application.properties from discovery-server:

```java
server.port=8761

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:${server.port}/eureka/
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

do the given changes in the WebClientConfig

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public WebClient.Builder webClient() {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);
    return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You error is because your DNS does not resolve `inventory-service` to any IPv4/6.

I don't know what this service is, but it is called/configured from your `OrderService`:

```java
InventoryResponse[] inventoryResponses = webClientBuilder.build().get()
                .uri("http://inventory-service/api/inventory",
                        uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("skuCode", skuCodes).build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(InventoryResponse[].class)
                .block();
```

You have to change this appropriately: from your configuration, we can see that your use a local database from a similar named service:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/inventory-service
```

If both service are started on the same machine, then you probably have to change `http://inventory-service` to `http://localhost:?/`:

- I used `?` because your inventory-service application.properties use `server.port=0`;
- I don't know for Spring Boot, but in most case, this will use a random port.

You could try to fix a port and use it in `OrderService`.

However, your `discovery-server` probably means that each of your service your use it to "discover" the actual end point.

For this, I can't help as I don't know Eureka (I suppose this is the discovery service from the name of the properties being configured).

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```java
@Autowired
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
```

instead of:

```java
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
```

Comment: It's giving the same error "2023-10-17T16:23:22.438-03:00 ERROR 26900 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Failed to resolve 'inventory-service' [A(1), AAAA(28)] after 6 queries ] with root cause
java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'inventory-service' [A(1), AAAA(28)] after 6 queries"